# Visual Studio Command guids for teamfoundation

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is there a command, menu and/or toolbar guid-reference for the teamfoundation specific things within visual studio?

There are alot of guids documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc826118(v=vs.110).aspx), unfortunately none of them are tfs related.

My greater goal is to provide a custom command when rightclicking on a changeset, which should be a farely simple task when the commandguid is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to  use the EnableVSIPLogging registry value, (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\x.0\General`), as described by this old article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

When the DWORD registry value below is set to 1, CTRL+SHIFT is pressed, and you attempt to display a menu or execute a command, a VSDebug Message dialog will be displayed containing the GUID and ID of that menu or command.

Referred links:

- https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-extensibility-id-and-guid-for-menu-item/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c5eb211-3985-426c-a3a2-9da4473dbaf4/my-context-menu-item-made-by-menu-command-in-visual-studio-package-is-not-shown-in-cshtml-files?forum=vsx
- http://magenic.com/Blog/Post/48/Developing-a-Visual-Studio-2012-Team-Explorer-Extension-for-Search-and-Replace-in-Work-Items

Comment: Works like a charm! Too bad you cant Copy&paste the data from the dialog :p

Comment: You can try the solution in the first link: if you type <CTRL-C> with any dialog box open, the contents will be copied to the clipboard as text.